Angular 18.2.2 @If(){} and Angular material problem
Hi i have a angular material table
<div class="background">
  @if (!this.isLoading) {
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tabelData" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
..rest of the table
</table>
}@else { 
    <div class="spinnerContainer">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
}

but when i try to delay the download of the data to it
ngOnInit() {
this.fetchTableDataService.getTableElements().subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
      // Set loading state if needed
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.tabelData.data = [...data];
        this.tabelData.sort = this.sort;
      }, 1000); // Delay data assignment
    },
}

it still gets the data when my page loads and whats weird at the begging i get
 and the table, mat spinner disapeers after 1 second
I think i should also specify that i turned on SSR when creating the project
I tried to delay download form my service
Like this
  return this.httpClient.get<PeriodicElement[]>(url).pipe(
    delay(1000) // Directly apply delay to the observable
  );


and like this
 return from(data).pipe(
    concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(1000)))
  );

but it did not work
i also tried to use *ngIf in table but the same thing happens as when using @if

UPDATE:
I used the first approach, where default there will be loading of 1 second.
The main problem was the setTimeout update was not triggering change detection, since the placeholder has a default time of 1second.
If you must use setTimeout, then you need to fire detectChanges using ChangeDetectorRef, so that the isLoading is updated in HTML.
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.tabelData.data = [...data];
          this.tabelData.sort = this.sort;
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log(data, this.isLoading);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }, 1000); // Delay data assignment

The final code will be the second solution in this below code.
Github Repo

When you use SSR, the value is cached when the request is made on the server.
When the same request is made on the browser the cached value is used, hence the table is loaded immediately.
For this scenario, what you can do is.

If you are ok with caching the value and just want to show the spinner for sometime, you can use @defer with a combination of @placeholder where you specify the minimum time, you want the spinner to show.
@defer {
  @if (!this.isLoading) {
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="tabelData" matSort class="mat- 
       elevation-z8">
              ..rest of the table
    </table>
  } @else { 
    <div class="spinnerContainer">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
  }
} @placeholder (minimum 1000ms) {
    <div class="spinnerContainer">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
}


Another way to solve the problem is to disable making the API call on SSR using afterNextRender callback (which runs only on the browser).
constructor() {
    afterNextRender(() => {

        this.fetchTableDataService.getTableElements().subscribe({
            next: (data) => {
              // Set loading state if needed
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.tabelData.data = [...data];
                this.tabelData.sort = this.sort;
                this.isLoading = false;
              }, 1000); // Delay data assignment
            },
            error: (error: any) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            },
        });
    });
}

This will ensure the API call is made when the page loads on the browser.

i dont think you can use afterNextRender in ngOnInit but it works in constructor.
and there is still an issue with my @if (it infinetly shows the spinner even tho the console.log(this.isLoading) changes

@ArtO have you set on push change detection? Remove it, changed to constructor

should i set it in my component ? coz i dont have it

@ArtO ok then without onPush  you are having this issue then, could you try {{loading}} in HTML outside of @if and check if it updates, best if you could share a stackblitz so that I can debug the issue directly.

https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Bartobloko/atiperaPeriodicProject here you go

@ArtO Thank you for the working example, please find my updated answer!
